# iText : unable to retrieve /Resources from a page

Tags: java, pdf, nullpointerexception, itext, pdf-manipulation

I'm using iText 5.0.1 to manipulate existing PDF. When analyzing an existing PDF using [RUPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/), I can see that the first page contains a /Resources :

[image]

However, when manipulating the PDF by using the [following example](http://osdir.com/ml/java.lib.itext.general/2004-09/msg00018.html), I'm getting a NPE because *pageDictionary.get(PdfName.RESOURCES)* is returning null.

Here is what my *pageDictionnary* object contains when debugging :

[image]

Unfortunately, because of confidentiality, I can't post the PDF now, but does anyone have an idea why I'm getting this NPE ? Or does anyone have an idea how to investigate further ? (I'm far from being an expert with iText and PDF structure ... and slowly getting out of idea)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample code you use assumes that the **Page** objects are immediate kids of the dictionary pointed to by the **Pages** catalog key:

```
PdfDictionary pages = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reader.getCatalog().get(PdfName.PAGES));
PdfArray kids = (PdfArray) PdfReader.getPdfObject(pages.get(PdfName.KIDS));
PdfDictionary pageDictionary = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject((PdfObject) kids.getArrayList().get(pageNum - 1));
```

This assumption often is ok because many PDF producers generate simple page trees, but in general the page tree can indeed be a *tree* with a *depth larger than 1*, i.e. its leafs, the **Page** nodes, may be deeper down in the structure, kids of kids of kids of the root **Pages** dictionary etc.

In case of your PDF that is the case, the **Page** dictionary of page 1 (object 3) is kid of the **Pages** dictionary object 6 which in turn is kid of the root **Pages** dictionary object 70.

Thus, that code assumes the intermediary **Pages** dictionary object 6 to already be a **Page** object.

This is not the only issue of that sample code, though. E.g. it also assumes that the **Resources** dictionary is attached to the **Page** object itself. This need not be true, it may also be attached to any parent **Pages** object including the page tree root:

> **Resources** dictionary *(Required; inheritable)* A dictionary containing any resources required by the page (see 7.8.3, "Resource Dictionaries"). If the page requires no resources, the value of this entry shall be an empty dictionary. **Omitting the entry entirely indicates that the resources shall be inherited from an ancestor node in the page tree.**
>
> *(Table 30 – Entries in a page object - in ISO 32000-1, the current PDF specification)*

So, the sample you use in general is useless as it does not honor the PDF specification.

---

That been said, your sample is from the time when the *newest version of iText* was *1.02b* while you are *using iText 5.0.1*... Why did you not look for a more current sample? It is a wonder that after 4 major versions it even can be tweaked to compile easily!

---

In current iText versions you can get the dictionary of a given page using the `PdfReader` method `getPageN(final int pageNum)` or `getPageNRelease(final int pageNum)`.

You should not expect the current `PdfReader` method `getPageResources(final int pageNum)` to return the resources of the given page, though, as it (just like your sample code) only looks at the **Page** dictionary for the **Resources** dictionary

---

Is there a specific reason for you to *use iText 5.0.1*? That version is pretty old and many bug fixes and features have been applied since then.